# calulator errors

Tags: calculator

My Sharp EL-531XH calculator appears to have a bug in the decimal to hex conversion, where any number with more than nineteen bits (>2^19) is in error. A few minutes produced the following table ...
Power   Hex
 (2^x)
20      1001A8
21      1FFF68
22      3FFED0
23      800188
24      FFFF28
25     1FFFE50
26     4000088
27     8000110
28     FFFFE38
29    20000058
30    4003F080
31    7FF89EC0
32   100007FC0
My questions: can anybody suggest a fix or workaround, or must I toss the device? If I need to buy a new one, are all Sharp calculators likely to be the same, or did I just get a bad model/batch/whatever?
All suggestions welcome.

Comment: Maybe it only shows and stores a certain number of digits.

Comment: Use LaTeX please.https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020